# Switching states within conditional statements in C#

Tags: unity, c#, state, fsm

In the usual `Update()` of a state (let's call it `Attack` for simplicity) of an object state manager `unit` called there's a conditional statement:

```
if (Condition a)
{
//do something
SwitchState(unit.anotherState)
//then do something else
}
```

What I don't understand is why, after switching states, `then do something else` continues execution? Clearly it should terminate execution of `Attack` and switch to `anotherState`.
So why doesn't it happen?

Comment: Because line of code are executed in order. Nothing is checking your `Condition a` before the next cycle of `Update`. Once `SwitchState()` is called, it will continue with whatever code you have below it.

Comment: This does not look like a question about how to develop a game, but a general programming question about the semantics of C# code. This type of question typically belongs on StackOverflow.

Comment: @DMGregory, could you elaborate on that please, as coding is a substantial part of creating a game. For me, and probably because I am pretty new on SE, this question would fail big time on StackOverflow where I find it more (or less) appropriate here as most here are exploring coding in general. Just learning gamedev and stackoverlow myself.

Comment: We generally expect questions here to be about topics that not just any programmer could answer, but rather that rely on some game-specific expertise. Understanding how control flow operates around `if`  statements and method calls is soundly in the former group: any programmer using an imperative language could explain this, and no game-specific expertise is needed.

Comment: Your assumption is wrong. The simplest way to think about it is that SwitchState(state) just tells "when doing the next Update() use different state".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your example but filling in what is happening

```
public class Class : Monobehaviour
{

    private int state = 0;

    private void Update()
    {

        if (Condition a)
        {
            //do something
            SwitchState(unit.anotherState)
            //then do something else
        }

    }

    private void SwitchState(int new_state)
    {
    
        state = new_state;
    
    }
}
```

The execution order is:

```
1. Update()
2. ->  if (Condition a)
3.     ->  //do something; state = 0;
4.         SwitchState(unit.anotherState)
5.         ->  state = new_state;
           <-
6.         //then do something else; state = unit.anotherState
       <-
   <-
```

Then on re-entering this Update() again, `Condition a` is most likely still the same but `state != 0`. This is an assumption and in coding `->` never assume anything.

---

Besides, this is a class not a state. Also this does make me think you ought to use switches rather then if-statements. No answer/comment here will change though. Reconsideration of your example will have a learning function as you call `unit` a statemachine, I tend to think `SwitchState` belongs in `unit`. As the statemachine is responsible for state-handling. Narrow all your code to the responsible class, it will help you not to repeat your code too.

---

When `SwitchState(...)` can fail to change the state, consideration of returning `true` on success of `false` on fail would create the ability to put the call into an if-statement to execute it's scope or not. Like:

```
if(!SwitchState(unit.anotherState)
{
    ...
}
```

If it will always change the state, code afterwards shouldn't be added when it doesn't suppose to be executed. In case of code after the if-statement should be executed, adding a `return` in the scope of the if-statement or an `else` will be your friends, so when the `Condition a` is not met, that scope is skipped and the code after it will be executed.

```
private void Update()
{

    if (Condition a)
    {

        //do something
        SwitchState(unit.anotherState);
        return;

    } // else

    if (Condition b)
    {
        //do something
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `SwitchState(unit.anotherState)` is a method. And when the method has finished, the program execution continues after the method-call.

If you don't want that, add a `return;` statement after the method call. This will finish the current method and return execution to the scope it was called from.

Comment: It sounds like this user might benefit from some clarification that the conditions in if statements are not checked continuously throughout a branch's execution. They're an instantaneous junction in the track, and once you pass the junction point, you stay on the rail you chose to wherever it takes you. They're imperative "check this condition and choose a track *now*", not declarative "execute this code *as long as* this condition holds".

Answer (score 0):

I’m going to rewrite your code using different names. And highlight why you would WANT this to work the way it does

```
if (Condition a)
{
    //do something
    SwitchState(unit.anotherState)
    //then do something else
}


if (Condition applesOnSale)
{

    OpenBasket();
    
    SwitchPeaches(to.Apples);

    RecaclulateTotalPrice();
}
```

If we want to recalculate our price after we’ve made a switch, we want to make sure that our code completes with all lines running. It wouldn’t make sense to skip that line, since we haven’t reached the closing } yet. Nothing from this code suggests that that line should be skipped.

I think what might be confusing you is that your switch method “shifts control” to the other class. But once that happens and completes it comes back and finishes this function.

We would never want the price recalculation to be skipped after we switch to apples. It’s just another step that occurs after the switch is complete!

Comment: That's how I implemented it in the end. I made my life harder by adding various IEnumerators without a thorough understanding of the methodology.